# I have a problem where my image wont show up

Tags: html

I referenced and image as  
I put my jpg image in public/assets/images folder.
I then build successfully with npm start, however, when I go onto my site the image isn't there. Please comment if you need any more information. Here are some screenshots
Thanks

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpc8e.png

Where the logo should show up (Sydney FC) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg7Pl.png

CODE:

```html
import React from 'react';
import './style.css'

export const ALeagueTeam = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <section id="one" class="tiles">
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                    <img src={require('../../images/sydney.jpg')} alt='' />
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">SYDNEY FC</a></h3>
                        <p>FOUNDED IN 2004</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">VIEW PLAYERS</a></h3>
                        <p>CURRENTLY 1st</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic03.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">MELBOURNE CITY</a></h3>
                        <p>FOUNDED IN</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">VIEW PLAYERS</a></h3>
                        <p>CURRENTLY 2ND</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">WELLINGTON PHOENIX</a></h3>
                        <p>FOUNDED IN </p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic06.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">VIEW PLAYERS</a></h3>
                        <p>CURRENTLY 3RD</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-star-g4rik?file=/src/App.js)

It doesn't look like your picture because I don't have your CSS, but the image should show. I don't know of a situation in JS programming where you use both the new module system `import` and an old module system such as CommonJS `require()`. I don't believe you should be using `require` anywhere in your react apps, if you are building with Create-React-App.